How do i remove the Function App name from an Azure APIM endpoint with a custom domain?
I am trying to figure out Azure's APIM at the moment and getting nowhere fast.
I have an Azure Function App:
FunctionApp Name: myFunctionApp
FunctionApp Route: /x/y/{z}/get
so the app function url is https://myFunctionApp.azurewebsites.net/api/x/y/{z}/get
i want to use azure apim to use a custom domain primarly to map multiple azure functions apps to be under a single domain for easy of use for web users.
However when the api creates an end point for a function app the endpoint is:
https://my-apim-name.azure-api.net/myFunctionApp/x/y/{z}/get
however the function apps name is in the url, which then create a less friendly and messy endpoint, i would like to be able to remove the function apps name from all api end points
So i want to be able to use:
https://my-apim-name.azure-api.net/x/y/{z}/get
if i use:
<rewrite-uri template="/x/y/{z}/get" />

i get resource not found

Lets say you have an Url https://xxx.azure-api.net/afreen-fa/Route1 wherein xxx.azure-api.net is host name , afreen-fa is API Url suffix and Route1 is Uri template. So you would like to remove the Url suffix before sending the request to backend which will result in {domainName}/{FunctionAppRoute}.
In order to remove the API Url suffix, you can use the below given policy.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <rewrite-uri template="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.Replace(context.Api.Path, string.Empty))" copy-unmatched-params="true" />
    </inbound>
</policies>

This policy will remove the url suffix.


If you want to pass the value of FunctionAppRoute dynamically and remove the FunctionAppName from the request Url then you the above given policy along with that follow the below steps-
I have imported a function app which has route x/y/{z}/get and it looks like below-

Then I added <rewrite-uri  template="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.Replace(context.Api.Path, string.Empty))"  copy-unmatched-params="true"  /> in inbound policy. My function works fine without using this policy too.
Invoking the request.






sorry I think I might not have explained it properly, I want the user to make a request to https://xxx.azure-api.net/Route1 which is actually https://xxx.azure-api.net/afreen-fa/Route1 as defined by the api

@EnenDaveyBoy Have you tried to use my policy?

Are you saying that you want to amend functionapp name?

I have tried to use your policy and its not working an I am a little confused. eg how will the apim know out of multiple api's in an apim know what the function name is? eg the apim endpoint is set as xxx.apim.com/myfunction/x/y/{z}/get but i want the user to call xxx.apim.com/x/y/{z}/get to call the same endpoint, the routes are all unique so i don't need the function names its makes the urls a lot less user friendly, there are multiple apis with different functions so the function name will be different

@EnenDaveyBoy so the value of z is dynamic here?

i added a dynamic element just incase it made a difference to the policy, so yes, sorry for the confusion

i have updated the op i still don't think we are on the same page

@EnenDaveyBoy I understood your requirement, so first use the same policy either in API level or in operation level, this policy will only remove the functionappname and will keep the url template like in your case /x/y/{z}/get and then follow the steps I added later in my answer like adding url template as /x/y/{z}/get this will work just fine

i added the rewrite policy to the inbound policy section in the design area, then removed the function app name from the request url and i get resource not found. does it take time for it to populate? like a dns server

@EnenDaveyBoy can you share the screenshot like this

i think i have it working, if i go in and remove the API URL suffix (from the endpoint settings tab) will that work without conflict? i also had to remove the url rewrite, but it is working on one endpoint at the moment

no i get a conflict when removing  using more than one

@EnenDaveyBoy can you share the screenshot of your Api and operation so that I can help you

can i ask what your API URL suffix is in the settings for that endpoint?

@EnenDaveyBoy API URL suffix is afreen-fa

this worked until i added another api, at which point it stopped.

nope turns out was using the functions url not the apims,  from my understanding the uri-rewrite doesn't affect the baseurl, and because the API Url Suffex is part of the base url your stuck, or at least i am

@EnenDaveyBoy I believe you are doing something wrong I am not sure what it is

while i certainly can't rule it out, i have confirmed that by url-rewrite is working using the trace statements, but one thing i cannot do in the portal is run a test which hasn't got the API URL Suffix in it, if the suffix is in the settings its in the test request url, which then works because it has the suffix, however when i do a test locally to the endpoint without the suffix it doesn't work with a 404 resource not found, so i genuinly don't know how your running your test to a url without the suffix.

I have suffix but it is getting removed by policy in my case which I shared in my answer

yes but the request has the suffix, so it works, i want to make a request without the suffix

@EnenDaveyBoy I believe it is not feasible, whenever you create any API in Apim then you need to provide api suffix as it is mandatory. You can remove it while sending the request to backend but in request url, you need to provide it

I don't suppose you know if I can put x/y/{z}/get in the API Url Suffex

@EnenDaveyBoy Yes you can.

In essence, you want requests to https://my-apim-name.azure-api.net/x/y/{z}/get to be redirected to https://myFunctionApp.azurewebsites.net/api/x/y/{z}/get.
Why don't you set up the API as follows?

Then, if you have the Operation Frontend set up like this, it should work as expected - no need to use complex policies:


because i want the tennentid in the url, and the your not allowed dynamic values in the api url suffix

@EnenDaveyBoy There's no "tennentid" in your question and there's no requirement to have it in the URL. The quality of the answers depends on the quality of the questions. If you can expand your question to clarify all your requirements, you are likely to get an answer that will work for you. If you mean the "x" in your URL should be variable and you don't want to have multiple APIs for different "x" values then I understand your problem. If this is something else, then probably I still don't understand what exactly your issue is as it is not clear from the question.

i want dynamic values in the url, thats is in the op, and i don't want to have an api url suffix thats is in the op, the naming of those values are irrelevent. I already know that if I import an azure function into an apim i cannot have it without a api url suffix azure support have confirmed it is the case, and they couldn't offer a way to use an azure function in apim that creates a clean url without an api url suffix
